# Redux store update is not showing up in props

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I created a validation action that looks like this:

```
export const validate = (requestObject, validationObject) => {

   return (dispatch) => {

   // First, clear any existing errors
   dispatch(clearErrors());

   // Call validation function
   const response = validateObjectFunction(requestObject, validationObject);

   // Set state for isValid
   dispatch(setIsValid(response.isValid));

   // Set error messages
   if(!response.isValid) dispatch(setErrors(response.errors));

   }
}

const setIsValid = (value) => {
   return {
      type: types.SET_IS_VALID,
      value
   };
}
```

In my handler function in my component, I simply call this validate action, then based on the state of `isValid`, I call my backend API.

```
handleClickSubmit () {

   // Form the request object for validation
   const request = {
      id: this.props.id,
      name: this.props.name
   };

   // Grab the validation object defined inside the compoenent that contains all validation requirements and call validate action.
   this.props.actions.validate(request, validationsObject);

   // This is where the issue is.
   // Although I know for sure, I hit the reducer and set the state of isValid to TRUE, when I get here the isValid is still FALSE
   if(this.props.isValid) this.props.actions.callApiFunction(request);
}
```

In my testing, I first just click submit so that the state for `isValid` is set to FALSE. I then enter data into all required fields in my form and hit submit again.

As the code executes, I see that I hit the reducer and set `isValid` to TRUE before hitting the line `if(this.props.isValid) this.props.actions.callApiFunction(request);`

It's important for me to mention that I do NOT have any `async` inside this process. All happening in memory.

Any idea what may be causing the state for `isValid` not to be updated quick enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Props wouldn't be updated yet in the redux lifecycle. I'm assuming you're setting props in mapStateToProps?

You could probably get the value out of state after calling the validate function, though I would probably recommend moving this into an action creator instead of the component.

Comment: This whole thing is happening inside an action creator except for the handler function. I don't understand why the props wouldn't be updated. They're reading directly from the store.

Comment: Right, props haven't been updated in your component yet, where the handler function is. This should be handled in the action.

Comment: If you look at the action creator code, I also set errors in there. My component gets the errors as props also and they update fine.i don't understand why only this one prop doesn't update.

Comment: Could you post your reducer?

Comment: This is definitely an issue stemming from order of execution. Basically, the redux store is updating but not before the next line of code executes. I was able to solve the issue by using a callback function. In the action creator, if the response is valid, I call the callback function so I don't have to wait for the Redux store to update. I think you were suggesting something along this line.